# Postgres SQL in clause and setArray()

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am using Java 1.7 and JDBC 4 and Postgres. I am trying to use a PreparedStatement with an array to fill a SQL in clause. But, the SQL generated seems to have "{" and "}" in it.  Here is the code:

```
PreparedStatement ptmt = 
      connection.prepareStatement("select * from foo where id in (?)");
String[] values = new String[3];
values[0] = "a";
values[1] = "b";
values[2] = "c";
ptmt.setArray(1, connection.createArrayOf("text", values));
```

The resulting SQL looks like this:

```
select * from foo where id in ('{"a","b","c"}')
```

Which, can't work. This is how it should look:

```
select * from foo where id in ("a","b","c")
```

or

```
select * from foo where id in ('a','b','c')
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When your database field is of type `array`, then you can use the `PreparedStatement.setArray()` to send an array to the query. But, in your case, it's not really an array, rather is a variable no of arguments, and you can't do that. i.e.

```
PreparedStatement ptmt =  connection.prepareStatement("select * from foo where id in (?)");
```

can take only one parameter. If you want 3 parameters to be passed, you have to do

```
PreparedStatement ptmt =  connection.prepareStatement("select * from foo where id in (?, ?, ?)");
```

And do `ptmt.setString(n, "String")` thrice.

If your no of arguments aren't constant, then construct the query dynamically, although, you loose the efficiency.

Answer (score 12):

Use  [= ANY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.28.16) subquery expression.

```
PreparedStatement ptmt = connection.prepareStatement("select * from foo where id = ANY(?)");
String[] values = new String[]{"a","b","c"};
ptmt.setArray(1, connection.createArrayOf("text", values));
```

And if you need to enforce types in the query you can do something like this.

```
select * from foo where id = ANY(?::text[])
```

The [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.28.16) has more details. This snippet is worth noting:

> SOME is a synonym for ANY. IN is equivalent to = ANY.

Comment: If anyone wants to use the NOT IN using this it can be used as `NOT ( id = ANY(?::text[]))`

Answer (score 5):

PostgreSQL has a couple of [array capabilities](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-array.html) that can handle this situation.

First is the unnest function, available since 8.4.  A little cludgy, but effective.

```
select * from foo where id in (SELECT * FROM unnest(?));
```

Next is the array intersection operator.

```
select * from foo where ARRAY[id] && ?;
```

Converts your column value into an array with a single element and then checks for intersection with the array that you set up as a parameter.

As best as I can tell, these are functionally equivalent, but I haven't checked which might be more performant.

Comment: A possible downside to `where id in (SELECT * FROM unnest(?))` is that is causes `getParameterMetaData` to fail with an exception: "ERROR: could not determine polymorphic type because input has type "unknown"". The other approach you suggested, `where ARRAY[id] && ?`, doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'd consider this a PgJDBC issue. It should really be writing an array constructor or an array literal with an explicit cast, eg:

```
select * from foo where id in (ARRAY['a','b','c'])
```

or

```
select * from foo where id in ('{"a","b","c"}'::text[])
```

As a workaround you should be able to write:

```
"select * from foo where id in ( (?)::text[] )"
```

.. though I haven't tested to verify that.

Please consider writing this up as a unit test for PgJDBC and submit it to the PgJDBC project via github as a bug report. Look at how the existing unit tests work and just add another. It's all pretty simple JUnit.

Comment: I was really hoping I could make this work. But, when I try: select * from teamdata where teamdata.teamid in ('{"t11","t54"}'::text[] ), I get "No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts." In my case, the id column is a varchar. Sorry about changing the query on you, but, that is the actual query I am using.

Comment: @DooDah Make sure you can run it by hand with `psql` first, work out the correct query and types. Then adapt to PgJDBC. `::text[]` is just a cast; you can similarly cast to `varchar[]`. Though in practice Pg will treat them as the same data type so I'm not sure that's the problem.

Comment: Gotcha. Will give that a try. Still learning some of the Postgres subltlies. Thanks for the tip. I will also try to submit this as a unit test for the PgJDBC driver.